# what percent of the combined class now has a higher GPA than Tom

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> In a class of 40 students, exactly 90% students had lower GPA than
>   Tom. For the new term, 60 students join Tom's class. If Tom's GPA is
>   higher than those of 80% of the new arrivals, what percent of the
>   combined class now has a higher GPA than Tom?

Problem: In the beginning 36 students has lower GPA than Tom. After 60 new students joining, total students= 100, and (48+36)= 84 students has lower GPA than Tom. In my perspective, I can say 15% students has higher or equal GPA than Tom. But, according to GRE prep book "Manhattan 5 lb", this 15 percent students are said to be has higher GPA than Tom. Is it correct?

Comment: There may not be _any_ with a strictly higher GPA. Likely just sloppy wording on their part.